# Java service memory usage varying

Tags: java, android, performance, memory, service

I created a service which reads every 10 seconds(`Thread.sleep`) new messages from an online text file(chat). When I look in the settings the memory usage starts at 4.0MB which is ok, but every minute later it is increased by 0.1 MB. This goes until 10Mb are reached, then it starts at 4.0MB again. And my service is after 2/3 hours fully terminated and never started again(but there is enough memory, phone was not used in this period).

```
public void MessageReader() throws Exception{
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    message  = "";
    try {
        final String textSource = "mytextfile.txt";
        URL textUrl;
        textUrl = new URL(textSource);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));
        String StringBuffer;
        while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            servercommands += StringBuffer;
        }
        bufferReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        executer();
    }
    addmessages();
}
public void MessageReader() throws Exception{
    MessageReader();
}
```

`MessagReader()` is executed in a new thread, `addmessages()` does until now only return to `MesssageReader()` (no `String`s stored).

Comment: I recommend not to use `+=` with Strings. Use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead. Though this may not be the solution of your problem, it surely will improve your memory footprint. Besides: The Thread.sleep is superfluent. Just use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: ok now I'am using a StringBuilder, but memory is increased again every minute...If I don't run this class as service then all is fine! Is it normal that reading a text file every 10 seconds is so heavy for memory? or is it stored like temporarily?

Comment: bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream())); this lines fills up the memory. Is there any solution to this? Maybe to create the Reader only one time? and only reading?

Comment: Problem was the Thread.sleep, after adding a Timer all is working fine.